# Customizing Responsive Themes Menu

Tags: menus, themes, responsive

I use the popular theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/responsive

I would like to change the color of one of the menu items and if possible also have a jquery popup from one of the menu items. How can I accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without getting your hands too dirty, a lot of themes come with a CSS editor built-in so you overwrite rules. Feel free to do this for simple changes, and just be wary that your changes could get overwritten if you decide to update your theme in the future. However, if you feel comfortable going deeper, you can FTP your own CSS file with changes. This is a bit more complicated but still rather simple, though I won't get into that at the moment unless you want to know more.

For the jQuery, I'm pretty sure you could google "custom jquery editor" or something akin to that and find a plugin for Wordpress that allows you to write your own custom JS in the dashboard as well. Same with the CSS though- if you want to FTP, you can go that route as well.